# Running the disjoint of two JUnit Test suites

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, test-suite

Say I have two JUnit test suites as SuiteATest and SuiteBTest. They have few common test classes. Is there a simple way to command JUnit to run these common test classes from the two test suites ?

Answer (score 0):

I use cpsuite's BaseTypeFilter(http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp) to group tests.

For example:

// suite a

```
public class A implements SlowTests {

}
```

// suite b

```
public class B implements SlowTests {

}
```

And you could add a test suite :

```
@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@BaseTypeFilter(SlowTests .class)
public class SlowSuite {
}
```

Or you could use Junit's Category feature(http://alexruiz.developerblogs.com/?p=1711)